# Draw a triangle of stars

Tags: c#, beginner, comparative-review

I decided to try to write half a pyramid of stars using programming because I wanted to see if I could do it, and I did it. However after comparing it to other people's solutions I started doubting that my way was the correct one, even though it does the same thing.

So I combined all three examples so that I could get an answer on which one is better and why. It doesn't have to be better in terms of performance, but it could also be better because the way the code is written is more logical etc.

Which one of these is the better implementation if you had to choose either one of them, and what's an even better implementation in your opinion?

```
//Example 1
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int r = 0; r <= i; r++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

```
//Example 2
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for (int r = 1; r <= i; r++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

```
//Example 3
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < i; r++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
*
**
***
****
*****
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: I have deleted the `java` tag, because the presented code is `C#`.

Comment: @Heslacher I was making the same edit.  I've also fixed the title and added some more appropriate tags.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really a Java programmer, but I think there's enough common ground here for me to comment.

Let's ignore performance - this isn't a performance-critical task - and concentrate on idiomatic, clear code that avoids tripping up the reader.

**Counting**

The basic difference between your 3 approaches is where you start counting.

1. Counts from 0, in both the outer and the inner loop
2. Counts from 1, again in both loops
3. Counts from 1 in the outer loop, and 0 in the inner loop

I would recommend against the 3rd option - anyone looking at your code will be confused by the change in approach, and will waste time wondering whether there was a good reason for the change. If you really need to mix approaches in code, it's best to add comments to explain why you've done so.

Both C# and Java inherit C's approach of 0-based arithmetic - think of arrays and Lists. On that basis I'd favour approach 1.

**Names**

The tendency to use letters such `i` and `j` for counters goes back to FORTRAN's implicit typing (incidentally `r` would be a bad choice as it wouldn't, as best I recall, be an integer). There's no good reason - other than years of tradition - to use it in a modern language, in my opinion.

In general, I prefer to see all fields and variables given clear, fully-written out names.

Apart from anything else, I believe that finding clear names for them helps the programmer (both the original programmer and anyone maintaining their code) ensure they fully understand what they are doing.

Even in a toy program like this, written as a learning exercise, I'd argue these disciplines are worthwhile (possibly particularly worthwhile as they will get the student into good habits).

In your case,

- the outer loop is looping over lines or rows of output, so I'd give
  the controlling variable a name like `lineNumber` or `row`.
- the inner loop is looping over stars being output, so I'd give the
  controlling variable a name like `stars`.

So I might write something like this (untested) code :

```
// Print triangle of stars, 5 rows high
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
{
    // the number of stars per row is one more than the row number
    for (int stars = 0; stars <= row; stars++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I don't really have more to add.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are many ways to achieve the same result like you have shown. I would suggest to always use the most readable way.
If you know your tools you could tackle this problem by analysing it like

- in the first line is one star
- in the second line are two stars
- in the third line are three stars
- ......
- in the hundredth line are hundred stars

which means

- in the first line repeat one star one time
- in the second line repeat one star two times
- .....
- in the hundredth line repeat one star one-hundred stars

One way to repeat a string is to use the [overloaded ctor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-string-ctor(system-char-system-int32)) of the `string` class, the other way is to use [`String.Concat()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-6.0#system-string-concat(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string)))) in combination with [`Enumerable.Repeat()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.repeat?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-repeat-1(-0-system-int32)).

This could lead to

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new string('*', i));
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", i)));
}
```

or if you would go one step further you could separate the creating of the output and the action of output by using methods like so

```
static IEnumerable<string> GenerateStarsWithNewString(int maxStars)
{
    for (int numberOfStars = 1; numberOfStars <= maxStars; numberOfStars++)
    {
        yield return new string('*', numberOfStars);
    }
}
static IEnumerable<string> GenerateStarsWithRepeat(int maxStars)
{
    for (int numberOfStars = 1; numberOfStars <= maxStars; numberOfStars++)
    {
        yield return string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", numberOfStars));
    }
}
```

Both methods will produce the same, an `IEnumerable<string>` which will be joined by `string.Join()` like so

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GenerateStarsWithNewString(5)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GenerateStarsWithRepeat(5)));
```

Comment: I like the use of the language facilities (which I don't know), and in this context, I'd agree with 1-based counting. But I'd still change 'i' to something more meaningful!

Comment: @MarkBluemel done

Comment: only partly done, I'd say. The main loop variable is still called 'i'.